# Is there a better way to convert byte array to an int?

Tags: java

The first 3 bytes of a byte array are just integers, is there a better way to convert them? So far I have this but it just feels like a bad way of doing it.

```
public int parse_code(byte[] bs) {
    char[] array = new char[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        array[i] = (char) bs[i];
    }

    // Dirty way of doing it
    return Integer.parseInt(new String(array));
}
```

Comment: are they signed or unsigned bytes?  Thats an important thing to know before we can tell if the above code is correct.

Comment: From the code above the bytes are obviously ASCII digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that there will always be 3 decimal digits at the beginning of the byte array you can just convert them into a integer directly:

```
public int parse_code( byte[] bs )
{
    int intval = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        intval = intval * 10 + ( bs[ i ] - '0' );
    return intval;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example code seems to associate the `byte`s with their ASCII value. The proper way to do that would be to use the `String` constructor that takes the `byte` array and a character set:

```
// note: throws charset exception that will never be thrown on a valid JVM
//  as all JVMs must support US-ASCII
Integer.parseInt(new String(byteArray, "US-ASCII"));
```

---

**Note**: If the `byte`s were not ASCII character values representing integers (e.g., it's just an `int` encoded as four `byte`s), then you would want to look at the [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class. It has helpers that can convert from the `ByteBuffer` into other buffers (e.g., [`IntBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html)) to enable simple allow looping if it's all one type (as opposed to a mixed message, such as an incoming C-struct or something). It also has the added perk of enabling endianness to be changed.

```
int bytesValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).getInt();
```

It's also worth noting, as x4u pointed out, that `ByteBuffer` does require the proper number of `byte`s for each value it gets. So, the above `getInt()` method will use the next 4 `byte`s and fail (with an exception) if there are [0, 3].

Comment: The "bytes" in question are digit characters, not binary values.

Comment: While this suggestion is correct for other problems is obviously doesn't apply here. Neither do ByteBuffers parse ASCII digits nor can they handle integers with a length of 3 bytes.

Comment: @erickson Modified already. @x4u You're right, but I do want to keep that bit in there for when people find this from searching (as the title will lead them here when they want the `ByteBuffer`).

Comment: @x4u But that is a good note on the 3 bytes part. I actually read it as 4, probably from the expectation that it be a 4 byte number.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert it in to int, the size of the array should be max 4 and the int not to exceed 214783647. Then:

`int i = (bs[3] << 24) + (bs[2] << 16) + (bs[1] << 8) + bs[0] ;`

Other things you have to know: which position in the byte array where it fits in the int (big-endian vs little-endian):
(instead the previous expression) maybe you need:
`int i = (bs[0] << 24) + (bs[1] << 16) + (bs[2] << 8) + bs[3] ;`

if not all 4 bytes present you have to check the length.

Comment: Test your approach against the OPs current method. You will see that it doesn't produce the same results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to convert three byte of ASCII text like `123` as `[49, 50, 51]` to 123.

```
public static long parse_code(byte... bs) {
    long value = 0;
    for(byte b: bs)
       value = value * 10 + b - '0';
    return value;
}
```

if you know it will always be 3 bytes.

```
public static int parse_code(byte... bs) {
    return bs[0]*100 + bs[1]*10 + bs[2] - '0' * 111;
}
```